# awk match command and memory usage

Tags: memory, awk

I realised that my `awk` script was using more and more memory as time goes, when I wasn't supposed to store anything in memory so I decided to do some tests.

This is a very simple script (mine is bigger, but I reproduce the problem on a very basic one). My `awk` script is used inside a `bash` script, the `$file` variable is the file on which the `awk` runs.

```
awk '       
{
    if(match($0,"word"))
    {          
        line=substr($0, RSTART - 20, RLENGTH + 20)
        print line
    }
}
' "$file"
```

If I execute this script on a big file, in which each line contains `word`, the memory usage of the `awk` script is raising super fast, even faster if I print to a file. I have to stop it before it freezes my computer. Do you have an idea what is causing this big memory usage ?
In my real script, the files are usually smaller and the `match` function is not triggered every line like in this function, but I would prefer to be sure nothing wrong  will happen.

EDIT : This problem doesn't seem to appear while using mawk, only with GNU awk, I have no idea why.

Comment: Not sure why you have put "$file" while mentioning Input_file? Also try to take a new session of server etc and check the memory and cpu by doing top or vmstat etc commands which will tell you what's going on in background.

Comment: I checked with top and the memory usage is 4% higher every 3 second update (on a 2 GB VM). It can go to 12% increase every 3 seconds if I print to a file. I didn't understand about the Input_file you mentionned, the script is running on the file stored in the `$file` variable.

Comment: So in command(whatever you have used) to find out the high memory and cpu does it shows this script is responsible for that? in top or htop you could sort it by memory or cpu and could see who is culprit.
Also you mentioned that file is coming from a variable, agree on it, so what operations are you doing before calling this awk? We may need to know those also in order to help you. Kindly do let us know all the details on same.

Comment: I can't give you all the details, but I tested it simply by specifying the file directly. In top, it shows that `awk` process is using much and much memory as time goes, and almost all 100% CPU, but I think this part is normal as there is nearly nothing running atm.

Comment: Yes I asked the same question yesterday but my post wasn't clear so I tried to explain differently my problem. I am currently doing my test with the exact example above and the problem occurs (no bash at all so, only awk script). I tested it with mawk instead of gnu awk, and the problem is not happening here. I'm confused ...

Answer (score 0):

Trying this alternative

```
awk '       
/word/ {
        # you can match here, if result of operation is needed for later action
        print "hello"
   }
' "$file"
```

match on every line induce some more computation like define the index of the longest occurence (testing lot of possibilities), ... so yes it is exponantial with file size (and line size inside)

If match is a conditionnal part that cannotn be separate from surrounding code, use at least index() in place of match() (or better `if( $0 ~ /word/)` if not other result than checking presence is the goal)

Comment: It works with `if( $0 ~ /word/)` but I was using match to get the index of the beginning of the expression with the `RSTART` value. I read that index doesn't work with regexp, and I may use it later so I am still looking for a solution similar to the `match` one.

Comment: optimization of the code/algorythm  need some more info about objective. What do you want to do with the match and associate information ?

Comment: I edited my example to have a better idea of what I am doing. I use the `match` function to get the beginning of the matching word with the RSTART value, and then extract a part of the line with RSTART and RLENGTH.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to appear while using mawk, only with GNU awk.

I solve the problem by using `LC_ALL=C` before the `awk` script, like this :

```
LC_ALL=C awk '       
{
    if(match($0,"word"))
    {          
        line=substr($0, RSTART - 20, RLENGTH + 20)
        print line
    }
}
' "$file"
```

EDIT : The problem doesn't appear on GNU awk 4.1.4. This seems to happen only on older version (mine was 3.1.3)

Comment: Setting LC_ALL should improve performance, not memory usage. If that's true then you need to report this major bug to the GNU folks so they can fix it. Email then at bug-gawk@gnu.org and make sure to include the OS, shell and gawk version you're running on (gawk --version | head -2). Actually, make sure you're on the latest gawk version (4.1.4 I think?) first and only followup if the issue occurs there, no point bothering them if you're on an old version.

Comment: My GNU Awk version was an old one (3.1 something). Updating to the last 4.1.4 version solved the problem.